# How to access an upstream (namespace) module instance details without knowing if it exists?

Tags: python, logging, namespaces, python-2.7, global-variables

Answer Credit to Leenert Regebro:
Apparently my instincts were right, and this is impossible.  And obvious as well since there was only one answer in two hours.
Thanks for all the coments as well.

My Google-foo is failing me.

I am writing a library of custom exceptions as a module, for use in multiple projects under a single publisher.  I may have no say in the other projects, or I may have a say.  So it could be in use both by me and others.  The "and others" is the problem here.  Within my exceptions module there will be specific functions for outputting tracebacks etc. to log files using the `logging` module.  This is fine for me, because I use the `logging` module.

But if someone else, not using `logging`, uses the exceptions library, I need to skip the logging part.  A try...except resolves this problem, but what if they ARE using `logging`?  In this case I need to be able to determine their logging scheme (console/file/stream, file names etc.)  This is so that I can create a sub-logger, which will write to their file (or console or what have you):

```
<snip>
their_logger = THE_FUNCTION_I_CANNOT_FIGURE_OUT_HOW_TO_WRITE()
temp_var = their_logger.name + ".ExceptionLogger"
myLogger = logging.getLogger(temp_var)
</snip>
```

Obviously I could create a separate class or function it instantiate my module and have it receive a parameter of type `logging.logger`, but I would prefer to idiot proof this, if it is even possible.

I cant even check a `global` or the `globals()` dict for a value that I know of, because the other programmer might not use one.

Is there any way to do this?  (Assuming my library has been imported, and possibly not by the top level application...)   I personally have never tried to get data from upstream in the namespaces to be available in a lower namespace without explicit passing, and I doubt it is even possible, but there are a lot of programmers out there, any one ever achieved this?

Comment: FYI, it's not necessary to put tags into your question title ;)

Comment: @Oli..LOL they werent meant as tags, just some way to seperate the question from hints about what the topic included.

Comment: you *can* get loggers hierarchy e.g., [`logging_tree` package](https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/logging_tree/blob/master/logging_tree/nodes.py) but you shouldn't as @Lennart Regebro pointed out.

Comment: @ J.F. -- My thanks, but as you pointed .... not good.   ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bad idea to include optional configuration by default. Instead of adding the logging specifics by default and then make some sort of wild guess hidden by a try/except to exclude it, put that part of code into a function, and call it from your code explicitly.

You can not idiot-proof things. In fact, the more magic and hidden logic you have, the less idiot-proof it will be, and soon it will instead be intelligence-proof where it becomes really difficult to understand the magic.

So go with your idea of making a function and passing in the logger instead.

Comment: +20 for _"the more magic and hidden logic you have, the less idiot-proof it will be, and soon it will be intelligence-proof"_.

Comment: @ Lennart and Burhan...Never encountered intelligence proof before....is that kinda like a child proof pill bottle?  (Debug proof I would certainly say though...)